# Tee command unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, tee

How can I tee all these services into a log file:

```
stop service 1
stop service 2
stop service 3
```

I want all these services logs go to a file

should I use :

```
stop service 1 | tee log1.log
stop service 2 | tee log1.log
stop service 3 | tee log1.log
```

Or:

```
stop service 1 
stop service 2 
stop service 3 | tee log1.log
```

I haven't found a question like this
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`tee` accepts the `-a` flag to append to a file. So you should be able to redirect the output from all three commands to a single file by executing:

```
stop service 1 | tee log1.log
stop service 2 | tee -a log1.log
stop service 3 | tee -a log1.log
```

(The first command will truncate any existing file)

Comment: i have this question for you ! what if the stdout is too large for tee ? how does it behave ! does it parse all stdout in a single shot or by chunk ?

Comment: @Shantesh: what do you mean? It behaves just like any other command which receives input through a pipe. The operating system will do all the buffering and blocking.

Comment: i am actually having some doubts and seriously need some help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657613/how-does-frequent-unix-tee-command-write-stdout-terminal-output-to-file-if-the

Answer (score 4):

Another way not using `tee` is to simply use a bash command group with a single redirection of `stdout` to a log file:

```
{ stop service 1; stop service 2; stop service 3 } > log1.log
```

Use the `>>` operator to append to the log file, or use the `&>>` operator to append both `stdout` and `stderr`. It's also possible to use a bash subshell instead:

```
( stop service 1; stop service 2; stop service 3 ) > log1.log
```

Comment: Or a simple command group `{ a; b; c; } >> log1.log`, which would not need a subshell to execute. Also, `&>>` would put both standard error and standard output in the log file, which may not be what is desired. Use `>>` to take just standard output. `>` may suffice,  since we're redirecting the combined output stream to a single file in one shot.

Comment: Thank you all a lot, but I need to use the tee function not only to copy a log to a file but also to view it since I'm using a tool called TWS and the logs have to appear on screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
stop service 1
stop service 2
stop service 3
} 2>&1 | tee log1.log
```

This treats the output of all three commands with a single redirection operation.  It also includes the errors in the log file.