# How does/frequent unix tee command write stdout terminal output to file? if the output is too big

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tee

I am redirecting some tool stdout to tee command so that current progress can be seen on terminal as well as in the log file

Here is the code snippet where I am running tool and its stdout is fed to tee command and this code snippet is written from tcl  script.

```
$(EH_SUBMIT) $(ICC_EXEC) $(OPTIONS) -f ./scripts/$@.tcl | tee -i ./logs/$@.log
```

I can see current real time progress on the terminal but the same observation is not seen in the log file! and it writes stdout to log file chunk by chunk

How does `tee` work? Does it write by blocks or time or both?
If block what is the minimum block size? If it is time what is minimum duration?

I need to parse real time log entries for some data analytics(as I read log file via `tail -f` and then push new data as the log file grows).

Comment: Is your progress written to stdout or stderr? Maybe your process/OS doesn't flush your buffers until they are full.

Comment: How exactly are you observing that the logfile is written chunk-wise? The tail -f command, for example, polls the file only once per second, giving the appearance of a file being written chuck-wise, even if they are not.

Comment: @Kees-Jan That's wrong. `tail` just sleeps if you pass the `-s` option.

Comment: @knittl  i am passing stdout only.

Comment: @Kees-Jan yes i am using tail -f command to observe the data in the log file and it is appearing by chunk ang meanwhile on terminal it is printing line by line.

Comment: @nos can't we some how change this 4kB to some other number ? or some option to flush data to login and when it reads ?

Comment: @hek2mgl Your comment suggests you think my original comment is incorrect. Do you have any evidence to support that? For my part: The manual for -s (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) seems to say that tail always sleeps, 1 second by default, but you can use -s to modify that number.

Comment: @shantesh: Tail will always give you chunks, because it sleeps. You could try to reduce the sleep time. Try tail -f -s 0.01 for example. Be aware that this will increase the cpu-usage of tail

Comment: @Kees-Jan My comment does not suggest, my comment clearly states: **you are wrong!**. Have you never tailed a log file before?? Tail is using `inotify`. Try `(trap 'kill 0' SIGINT ; tail -fF test.log & while true ; do date  >> test.log ; sleep .1 ; done )` .. Are you convinced?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Thank you for more clearly stating your opinion. Please note, though, that I'm not universally wrong. Yes, I've tailed a log file before. Last time I investigated this issue, I was using (for various reasons) Ubuntu 8.04. At the time, I was correct. Yesterday, I re-investigated on a cygwin environment (unfortunately), and there, I'm still correct. Thank you for pointing out that the tail-people have made some progress since then.

Comment: @Kees-Jan In a cygwin environment, `inotify` is not available since it is a kernel feature. In that case **you are right**! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless programs handle buffering on their own, buffering of IO streams is handled in the libc. The standard behaviour is: Buffer output line wise if it goes to a terminal, buffer output block wise if it goes to a non-terminal, meaning a file or a pipe. That's why the output appears in log file as you described it: chunk by chunk. This behaviour is for performance optimization.

On Linux the [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) command can be used to run a program with adjusted buffers. You need to run your program like this:

```
stdbuf -oL your_program >> your.log &
tail -f your.log
```

`-oL` means buffer stdout linewise.

Comment: Thanks for the other approach/solution let me try it first but whole office setup is like this, it's hard for me to change something significant.

Answer (score 3):

From [the POSIX spec for `tee`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html), emphasis added:

> The tee utility shall copy standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files. **The tee utility shall not buffer output.**

So -- `tee` isn't your problem. Almost certainly *your program* is buffering what it's writing to stdout (which is default in many programming languages, including C, when stdout is not to a TTY).

```
stdbuf -oL yourProgram | tee file
```

...will, if your program is relying on the standard C library to determine its default behavior, suppress that.